# How to move a canvas object with mouse if they're not at the same position?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

Moving the object at the same position with the mouse is easy, what I would like to do is  having a full window canvas with a circle at 500, 500. If I click anywhere, from that point any position change of my cursor would affect the circle the same way.

e.g. If I move right 50px the circle also moves right 50px while keeping the initial distance etc.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the position of the circle independent of where the mouse is, I would suggest keeping 2 variables storing the x and y coordinates of the circle, and every time the mouse moves, you can update those variables with the change in x and y components of the mouse movement. If you are trying to make the circle at the same exact position of the mouse, you can just assign the circle to position of the mouse whenever there's a mouse movement.

hope this helps